# Why does not the page load entirely?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, drupal, lamp

If I load a page on my Drupal 8 site with a reliable internet connection, the site will stop loading after about 20 seconds.

My server is on LAMP. How to get the page to load completely ?

[image]

Comment: If it is exactly 20 seconds, probably a timeout setting getting triggered.  Otherwise, your application is way to slow.  20 seconds to load a web page is not reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

It can be that your theme or some of the user modules is causing the issue.

Check under `Reports -> Recent log messages` to see if some error is logged.

Also you could try disabling theme or modules (temporary) to see if this will continue.

Then, under `Configuration -> Development -> Performance` see if the caching is turned on. It should be on for production environment.

In your browser go inspecting, go to "Network" tab and reload the page. See if there are some request that take unusually long time.

Ask some of your friends to test the site.

At end, host server may be really slow or miss configured... Check for logged errors on server (PHP errors, Apache errors).